# XPath to choose root node based on GrandChild value

Tags: xpath

I have a XML FIle which is shown below--

```
<ROOT>
    <account name="ABC" code="XX">
        <row>
            <field name="ID">7650987</field>
            <field name="Length">00:02:37</field>
            <field name="Verif">6064625</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="ID">7651474</field>
            <field name="Length">00:01:08</field>
            <field name="Verif">6065064</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="ID">7651105</field>
            <field name="Length">00:00:42</field>
            <field name="Verif">6064737</field>
        </row>
    </account>
```

I need to extract the "code="XX"" based on the Verif value.

I am able to grab the Verif value using Xpath & then I tried reaching root using Parent syntax like,

/ROOT/account/row/field[@name='ID' and text()="7650987"]/parent::*

Above expression is returning blank.

How do I change the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your XML ROOT tag is not closed. Your XML should finish with 
`</ROOT>`. No xpath would work till you **fix the malformed xml**. When you close it, your attempted solution would not be blank anymore, although it won't be correct: `/ROOT/account/row/field[@name='ID' and text()="7650987"]/parent::*`:
This means return "The parent of a 'field' that has name of 'ID' and text of '7450978'", which would be a whole block of XML:

```
<row>
    <field name="ID">7650987</field>
    <field name="Length">00:02:37</field>
    <field name="Verif">6064625</field>
</row>
```

Now, what you need is: "The code value of an 'account' that has a child 'row/field' with name of 'ID' and text of '7450978'"

This can be translated as:

```
//account[row/field/@name="ID" and row/field/text()="7650987"]/@code
```

I tested it in online XPATH tester and works.

Answer (score 0):

Try ending your xml ROOT

```
<ROOT>
    <account name="ABC" code="XX">
        <row>
            <field name="ID">7650987</field>
            <field name="Length">00:02:37</field>
            <field name="Verif">6064625</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="ID">7651474</field>
            <field name="Length">00:01:08</field>
            <field name="Verif">6065064</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="ID">7651105</field>
            <field name="Length">00:00:42</field>
            <field name="Verif">6064737</field>
        </row>
    </account>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: My ID value is unique so it will be available in only 1 row child.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
/ROOT/account[row/field[@name="ID"]="7650987"]/@code
```

will return the `@code` attribute of the `account` element which has a `row/field` element with an `@name` attribute value of `"ID"` and string value of `"7650987"`, as requested.